# How to replace content ViewController inside other View controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am working on an application which allows users to work with a couple of workmodes. Main view of the app contains information common to all workmodes. I want to create a "subview" with ability to change its ViewController. This subview will be used to display information connected with specified workmode. It is important that app goes to MainViewController from WorkmodesViewController in which user chooses workmode to work with.

My question is:
Which tehnique should I use to acheave changeable WorkmodeViewController inside MainViewVontroller

[image]

Comment: The best way to accomplish this is from your delegate window. You can always change your rootViewController at run time so you can go all the way back to the beginning of the app and instantiate one VC or the other. If this is something that you are interested on let me know and I will post some code. Good luck!

Comment: I would be great if you post some code :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have found example git project with functionality I need:

https://github.com/mluton/EmbeddedSwapping